# Java 11 compiler not recognizing static BiFunction in main method

Tags: java, lambda, compiler-errors, functional-programming

I've been trying to give functional programming in Java a try. However, when I use a functional interface in a class as a first-class variable, my variables are not recognized when I compile.

I have attempted to make it a local variable within `main`, but received the same results.

Am I missing something here?

Code:

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

class Question {
    static final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add = (a,b) -> a+b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Question.add(1,2));
    }
}
```

Error Received:

```
Question.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(Question.add(1,2));
                                   ^
  symbol:   method add(int,int)
  location: class Question
```

Version Info:

```
javac 11.0.6
openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14
Ubuntu 18.04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Question.add(1,2)` is a method call, while `add` is a field.

```
class Question {
  static final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add = (a, b) -> a+b;

  static final int add(int a, int b) {
    return add.apply(a, b);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // calls the method
    System.out.println(Question.add(1,2));

    // gets the field and calls BiFunction's method
    System.out.println(Question.add.apply(1,2));
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I TOTALLY forgot that apply was necessary to call the function! Thank you so much!

Comment: `static final int add(int a, int b)` is in itself a bi-function, if you look at it that way.

Comment: @Naman exactly, I was about to write `return a + b`, but then, wait, let's reuse the code :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not that it doesn't recognize `add`, it's that `add` isn't a method - it's an instance of `BiConsumer`. You can't call it as if it were a method, you need to call its `apply` method:

```
System.out.println(Question.add.apply(1,2));
// Here -----------------------^
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no special syntax for calling *functional interfaces*.

```
System.out.println(Question.add(1,2));
```

To make the call requires invoking the actual function as normal.

```
System.out.println(Question.add.apply(1, 2));
```

The `add` variable doesn't need to be qualified.

```
System.out.println(add.apply(1, 2));
```